# 500 Internal Server Error php

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

En mi servidor mi formulario que uso para login no se está ejecutando. Este proceso lo hago en el index.php y despues del tag de head:

```
require "header.php"
```

Dentro de esto tengo 2 formularios en un div, dentro de este div se abre un if, con un objeto con el nombre de `'login-submit'`:

```
<?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
                echo '<a href="admin_panel.php">Panel de Control</a>
                        <form action="includes/logout_user.php" method="POST">
                            <button class="logout-btn" type="submit" name="logout-submit">
                        <div class="logout-btn"> <img src="img/icons/logout-icon.svg"> Desconectar </div>
                        </form>';
            } else {
                echo '<form class="login-access" action="includes/login_user.php" method="POST">
                        <input class="login-header-input" type="text" name="mailuid" placeholder="Correo/Usuario">
                        <input class="login-header-input" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
                            <button class="login-btn" type="submit" name="login-submit">Ingresar</button>
                    </form>';
            }
            ?>
```

Después en la página no e podido ser capaz de entender el error, o porque marca un 500 cuando el `login_user.php` es ejecutado. En mi `index.php` abro la sesión con un objeto de `user_id` <- que en mi "login_user.php" se encarga de emparejar con la columna en mi base de datos, esa sesión, dentro del index.php se ve así:

```
<?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
                    echo '<p style="color:green;">Estás conectado</p>';
                }
            ?>
```

No sé si fui claro o no porfavor háganlo saber, o si me falto explicar o copiar más código, espero y alguien sepa como resolver ésta situación, gracias.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {

        require 'dbh.php';

        $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];

        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password)) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=campovacio");
            exit();
        }
        else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid_users=?";
            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
                exit(); 
            }
            else {
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $mailuid);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                $results = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                    $password_check = password_verify($password, $row['user_password']);
                    if ($password_check == false) {
                        header("Location: ../index.php?error=claveinvalida");
                        exit();
                    }
                    else if ($password_check == true) {
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id_user'];
                        $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uid_users'];

                        header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                        exit();
                    }
                    else {
                        header("Location: ../index.php?error=claveinvalida");
                        exit();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?error=nohayusuario");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: revisa los archivos de log de apache/nginx o lo que estes usando para interprete de php. Suele venir mas informacion (sobretodo si es un 500, puede que nos diga mas informacion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible que te falte añadir lo siguiente al principio de cada archivo php en el que usas la sesión:

```
<?php
    session_start();
```

Esas líneas son las primera que deben aparecer en cada archivo php que use la sesión.